# Error when i generate barcode in itextpdf

Tags: itext, barcode

i have this probleam , where i´m work they buy a generate barcode,   idautomation is the software

they ubicate in a server the direction is:

```
Cbarra = Image.getInstance("http://200.36.25.89/CodeBarNew/LinearServlet?BARCODE="+strCadenaCodBarra+"&PT=T&ST=Y&BAR_HEIGHT=1&EM=.06")
```

strcadenacodbarra= Ê415770999800426980200000709388Ê39000010454400Ê9620161014

but the codebar work in my local machine. But when i put in server the code bar throw error. 
this is the code for put in the pdf

```
Cbarra.scaleAbsolute(305, 75);
cellCobBarrasImg = new PdfPCell(Cbarra);
cellCobBarrasImg.setPadding(0);
cellCobBarrasImg.setMinimumHeight(90);
```

thx for help.

Comment: *"when i put in server the code bar throw error."* - **Which error** is thrown?

Comment: Voting to close this question because there's not enough information: no Servlet code is shown, no specific error message is provided. It is hard to understand the broken English.